# Почему качество Java GUI существенно снижается после упаковки в exe?

Tags: java, libgdx, exe

Я использую **jpackage** для того чтобы преобразовать **jar** файл в **exe**, при этом **exe** файл будет обеспечивать внутренняя JRE. В результате преобразования получились хорошие результаты, JRE весит около 38,5 мб.

Когда я запускаю **exe**, качество GUI в два раза **ХУЖЕ**, чем в обычном **jar**! Кроме того окно нового **exe** файла самостоятельно увеличивается. Таким образом, появляются очень странные изменения, как будто **exe** файл пытается имитировать окно **jar** файл. Хочу отметить, что я использую **libGdx** для GUI.

**Часть gradle desktop**

```
task dist(type: Jar) {
manifest {
    attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
}
dependsOn configurations.runtimeClasspath
from {
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
with jar
destinationDirectory = file("$buildDir/lib")
```

}
jpackageImage.dependsOn dist

dist.dependsOn classes

eclipse.project.name = appName + "-desktop"

runtime {
options = ['--strip-debug',
'--compress', '2',
'--no-header-files',
'--no-man-pages',
'--strip-native-commands',
'--vm', 'server']
modules = ['java.base' ,
'java.desktop',
'jdk.unsupported']
distDir = file(buildDir)

```
jpackage {
    jpackageHome = 'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-17.0.2'
    mainJar = dist.archiveFileName.get()
    if (osName.contains('windows')) {
        imageOptions = ["--icon", file("../icons/icon.ico")]
    } else if (osName.contains('linux')) {
        imageOptions = ["--icon", file("../icons/icon.png")]
    } else if (osName.contains('mac')) {
        imageOptions = ["--icon", file("../icons/icon.icns")]
    }
}
```

}

Сравнение:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Странная проблема, сам с ней столкнулся. Что делать не знаю, ответа так и не нашёл. Но эта мысль, что на самом деле jpackage просто перерисовывает jar окно в exe окно. Так что jar файлы лучше.

Comment: Что такое `качество GUI`?

Comment: Скриншоты бы хоть добавили. Вместо текста люди усиленно постят картинки, а когда пришел черед сравнить изображения почему-то описывают их текстом...

Comment: Сделано, картинки добавил

Comment: Короче, я придумал! Скомпилируй-ка свой проект с помощью RoboVM в машинный код и тогда всё будет нативно и быстро - это первый вариант. Или перепишии все на C++, ещё лучше вариант. Либо попробуй устаревший Pakr - крайний вариант. Короче, вам тут удачи. Всем спокойной ночи. 

Comment: GUI - это графический пользовательский интерфейс